# Is it possible to use Google Docs Viewer to view files already in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

The title is a little confusing. I'll elaborate.

As far as I can tell, the **[Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)** tool accepts a link to a raw document file (e.g. .doc, .pdf, et. al.), and renders its contents in the browser. For example, this url to a pdf `http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf` when passed to **Viewer**, returns this link: `http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf`

What I'm trying to achieve is, use the **Viewer** to view a document *already* hosted in **Google Docs** (i.e. no longer a raw document file). When passing a link to a **Google Docs** document to the **Viewer**, the result is not as expected. It renders the link's HTML source instead of the document's contents.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to be able to use the "embed" feature of **Viewer** to view **Google Docs** documents. Does **Google Docs** have a "link to embeddable view" feature?

**P.S.** Here is a sample snippet to an embedded document. This is what I want, but pointing to an existing **Google Docs** document.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've found a workaround.

Firstly be sure to have set the document sharing to *anyone with the link*.

Then, in the list view of Google Docs/Drive, select your document and click *More > Download...* and choose whatever format you want (e.g. PDF). The URL that appears for a second when you finally click *Download* is the URL you need (the one that works with Google Viewer).

For text documents you can get the same URL by taking the document editing URL, e.g.:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/ [alphanumeric code] /edit
```

And change it like that:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/ [alphanumeric code] /export?format=pdf
```

For other document types it's a bit different.
Presentation:

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/ [alphanumeric code] /edit
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/ [alphanumeric code] /export/pdf
```

Spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key= [alphanumeric code] 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/fm?key= [alphanumeric code] &fmcmd=12
```

I don't have tried with uploaded files or other formats, but hope it helps.